# (Help)Apk Decomplied unreadable files

Tags: decompilation, apk

I'm developing an android-based game for my school project.
I chose an .apk to reference the visual parts.
I've decompiled the .apk file I've specified. I can't view the image files I need.
files available but unreadable.I couldn't get a data hand using the existing .atlas editor.I will very happy if you help,I can send the apk file and images.

I have .json .atlas .png but just .atlas and png unreadable ( i tried with .atlas editor it doesnt work)

Sample : [image]

Comment: Open it in any hex viewer and see the magic number. Or use `file` tool in *nix system.

Comment: Can you rewrite this question to make it clearer what you are asking for help with? Ask questions that are specific (for example, show the unreadable output from the decompiler, describe what you did, and ask what is necessary to get a correct decompilation in reverse-engineering scenario.)